# Vue.js data object not getting updated on mounted - vue-file-uploder

Tags: vue.js

I'm working with the vue-media-upload library (documentation available [here](https://github.com/saimow/vue-media-upload))

I render the uploader component, and prepupulate it with an images array:

```
 <Uploader
    :media="images"
 />

export default {
    props:{

    },
    mounted(){
        this.getData()
    },
    data(){
        return{
        
            images: [
              
            ],
        }
    },
    methods:{
        getData(){
           
            axios.get('sections/slides/1').then(response => {
                    this.images = response.data;
                })
        },
  }
```

As you can see on the code, onMounted I call the getData function which fetches the images from the backend and update the images array. But for some reason, the uploader component fails to get populated with the images from the server.

Please not that if I try to display the images from the server like so {{ images }}, I can see the images object..but the upload component fails to get populated with the images.

if I hard code the images in the data object like so:

```
images: [
   { id: 1, name: '123_image.jpg' },
   { id: 2, name: '456_image.jpg' },
],
```

the uploader does get populated, but I don't want to hardcode the images, I want to get them from the server.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Template code is executed sychronously, whereas your data fetching is asychronous, meaning your Uploader component is always created with an empty `images` array.

Using [conditional rendering](https://vuejs.org/guide/essentials/conditional.html) you could add a `v-if` to wait to render/create the Uploader component until the `images` array is populated.

```html
<Uploader
    v-if="images.length > 0"
    :media="images"
/>
```

Comment: Thanks a million times